# Cannot remove extension from Chrome in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I searched for and found many articles about how to remove a rogue extension from chrome that has been grayed out. Almost all of the articles are for Windows users and did not apply to my case, hence I decided to post this question.

I tried deleting everything as per [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20180916165113/http://www.kuijjer.com/post/1367862444/how-to-remove-a-google-chrome-extension-on-mac-os). Also disconnected and deleted my profile from Chrome, tried to reset the Chrome settings and even uninstalled several times, however this extension called `DGExtension` cannot be deleted permanently.

Under `chrome://policy/`, I noticed ExtensionInstallForcelist with value (`jhafcpmngmieaimhldennincnemljiph;http://localhost:55556/service/update2/crx`), but there is no way to delete it.

Can you please help?

- **Chrome**: Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)
- **Mac OS X**: Version 10.10.5
- **Problematic Extension**: DGExtension 6.2.3.3046
- **ID**: `jhafcpmngmieaimhldennincnemljiph`
- **Message**: This extension is managed and cannot be removed or disabled. Installed by enterprise policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is managed by your corporate policy. You need to check with your company IT Admin if its causing trouble. Of course it will be a little slow.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to do the backups before you follow this guide

1. edit the plist files in `/Library/Managed Preferences/${whoami}/com.google.Chrome.plist` and `/Library/Managed Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist`, or `/Library/Preferences/..` (edit every occurrence of `com.google.Chrome.plist`) on your computer. Remove the `ExtensionInstallForcelist` part. (you may need to use `plutil -convert xml1` and `plutil -convert binary1` to convert the list into an editable format and convert it back)
2. In `System Preferences` → `Profiles`, find the profile that starts with "Chrome" and has "ExtensionInstallForcelist" in its value, delete it.
3. run `defaults read com.google.Chrome.plist` in terminal
4. start chrome, go to `chrome://policy/`, click `Reload Policies`
5. restart chrome, the extension should be gone